# click is not triggering inside directive due to event stoppropagation from outside

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click, stoppropagation

I have a `directive` and its child element (inside directive template) has `click` event. The element outside the directive(section tag) has another `click` event. So, I need to use `stopPropagation` in order to avoid the click to pass upwards to the `section` tag. But, the click is not passing to the child element of directive too. How can I solve this issue.

**main template:**

```
<section ng-click="doSomething()">
    <div ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()"> //Here where the problem comes..
        <myDirective></myDirective>
    </div>
</section>
```

**directive template:**

```
<div>
    <div ng-click="doDirectiveThing()"></div>
</div>
```

Here, when I call the `$event.stopPropagation()` the click is not passing to the child element of directive too.

Help me solve this. 
Thank you...

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem. Here's a [code chunk](https://jsfiddle.net/ruw0comh/1/) relative to your description.

Comment: Just in case, `doDirectiveThing` function should be written inside the directive controller if your directive scope is not `false`

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this... If I understood it correct you don't want to propagate the click event from directive to section.

**main template:**

```
<section ng-click="doSomething()">
        <myDirective></myDirective>
</section>
```

**directive template:**

```
<div>
    <div ng-click="doDirectiveThing();$event.stopPropagation()"></div>
</div>
```